# What does it mean that two numbers are within two decimal places of each other?

Tags: real-numbers, decimal-expansion

Sorry that this seems like an easy question but I find myself getting confused. What does it mean that two numbers are within two decimal places of each other? Does it mean that when these two numbers are rounded off to two decimal places and you subtract them, you get zero?

Comment: The phrase is a little ambiguous, but if I had to define it, I would say it means that the absolute value of their difference is less than $0.005.$

Comment: The description in the question is which I would use for the given statement. But more practical is the description suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Hmmm...makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: It is good to question & clarify these things. Too many careless people bandy about ambiguous statements with authority and leave thoughtful folks in a position of self doubt.

Comment: (I am one of those careless people :-).)